# Mono 2.10.9 is succeeding in making an SSL connection even though the certstore is empty

Tags: wcf, ssl, mono, certificate

I'm trying to test some customer scenarios due to a change in server SSL certificates. When installing our product, which runs on Mono 2.10.9 on SUSE Enterprise 11 SP3, we install CA certs to the Trust store. We now have to change our server certificates and in testing them I a seeing strange behaviour. Before installing the new self signed test CA cert, I ran the application to confirm that the certificate would not be accepted (not in the store). To my surprise, it connects fine. Can anyone shed any light on why mono would not throw an exception if the CA cert is not in the store.

To make certain, I deleted all certs from the machine and user cert store. I have queried the cert store, using certmgr and manually browsed the cert store folders. My understanding of this version of mono is that is must have the CA loaded in the store to work, however it seems to be working fine without it.

**Any ideas, this is driving me nuts???**

Below is the script I use to check the cert stores and results.

stores=("CA" "Trust" "AddressBook" "My")
ums=("user" "machine")

echo Start Read > certificates.txt
for um in ${ums[@]}
do
    if [[ $um = "user" ]]; then m=" "; else m="-m"; fi
    for store in ${stores[@]}
    do
       echo "=================================================" >> certificates.txt
      echo $um $store >> certificates.txt
      certmgr --list -c $m $store >> certificates.txt
    done
done
echo End Read >> certificates.txt

OUTPUT:

## Start Read

user CA
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
user Trust
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
user AddressBook
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
user My
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
machine CA
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
machine Trust
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
machine AddressBook
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

=========================================================================================
machine My
Mono Certificate Manager - version 2.10.9.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

End Read

Checking Cert Store Folders
suse:~ # ls -R /usr/share/.mono/certs/

/usr/share/.mono/certs/:
AddressBook  CA  My  Trust

/usr/share/.mono/certs/AddressBook:

/usr/share/.mono/certs/CA:

/usr/share/.mono/certs/My:

/usr/share/.mono/certs/Trust:

suse:~ # ls -R .config/.mono/certs/

.config/.mono/certs/:
AddressBook  CA  My  Trust

.config/.mono/certs/AddressBook:

.config/.mono/certs/CA:

.config/.mono/certs/My:

.config/.mono/certs/Trust:

---

Probably should have mentioned that this is a WCF service. The Client was built using wsdl & gcms. I have an equivalent service built in Visual Studio that runs on Windows using the same app.config which fails correctly when the root CA is not available in the Windwos Cert store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TestServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="1048560" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048560"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"  realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://my.test.url/app_dev.php/SOAP/v5"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestServiceSoap"
          contract="ServiceClient.TestServiceSoap" name="TestServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For completeness I should mention that I am testing on a Virtual Box image with the DNS configured in /etc/hosts and NATing onto a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Maybe your (unknown) code disables certificate validation? This would not be the first case where developers disabled validation because it was just in the way when testing.

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that this is a WCF service. The Client was built using wsdl & gcms. I have an equivalent service built in Visual Studio that runs on Windows using the same app.config which fails correctly when the root CA is not available in the Windwos Cert store.

Comment: Mono 2.x is super old, please test with a recent version of mono, you may be surprised at finding your bug fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading mono is not an option, our customers are very slow to upgrade anything and it will take them months to manage this type of upgrade across their estate.